# Automatic versioning of static files in GAE/P

Tags: javascript, css, google-app-engine, cache-control

I've been playing with Google's page speed service so I'm motivated to automatically version my static files in my GAE/P app so I can take advantage of longer caching times.

It seems straightforward to write a script to do the following:

1. Get a hash of static file contents.
2. Modify the file name to include the hash.

But how do I change my app engine templates to automatically refer to the new filename?  I suppose I could put some kind of marker in my templates and have the same script modify the templates, but this seems kinda hacky to me.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the app version (in `app.yaml`) should do what you need. Think of the app version as a (usually) hidden part of the namespace.

Comment: Unfortunately, not easily. Looking again at what you're trying to do, the easy answer would be to append a query string (per the advice in http://webassets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/expiring.html, but note the caveat). The safer approach is to include some hash or sequence in the path of the static asset. You could do the latter by keeping assets you want to have long expiry times on in a subfolder, then change that subfolder name every time you pushed new versions (e.g., "static/1/foo.jpg" -> "static/2/foo.jpg")